# Given a sentence containing several words and numbers. Find the largest number among them which does not contain 9

Tags: python

Given a sentence containing several words and numbers. Find the largest number among them which does not contain 9.

```
class Solution:
    def ExtractNumber(self,S):
        #ode here
        n=[int(i) for i in S.split() if i.isdigit()]
        for i in n:
            n1=i
            while(i>0):
                if(i%10 == 9):
                    n.remove(n1)
                    break
                i=i//10
        m=n[0]
        for k in n:
            if k>m:
                m=k
        return m
```

what is wrong with this function as it says error like

```
Runtime Error:
Runtime ErrorTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/201740db89118db90839eac44cdd8c21.py", line 31, in <module>
    ans=ob.ExtractNumber(S)
  File "/home/201740db89118db90839eac44cdd8c21.py", line 17, in ExtractNumber
    m=n[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't remove a value from a list whilst iterating.

Comment: What happens if the input list does not contain numbers that don't have a 9 in it? What is `n[0]` supposed to access?

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to get a item from the list without checking if there are any elements left in the list.

An alternative approach to this would be to use max.

```
def ExtractNumber(self,S):
    #ode here
    n=[int(i) for i in S.split() if i.isdigit()]
    return max(n, key=lambda x: x if "9" not in str(x) else -1)
```

or

```
def ExtractNumber(self,S):
    return max(int(i) for i in S.split() if i.isdigit() and "9" not in i)
```